# How to install gnu gettext (>0.15) on windows? So I can produce .po/.mo files in Django

Tags: python, django, windows, gnu, gettext

When runing `django make messages`:

```
./manage.py makemessages -l pt
```

I get:

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

I tried to install but the last version I find with an Instalation Setup is 0.14. Where may I find a recent version and how do I install it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is to download the [precompiled binary installer](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html). Download the "static" flavor of your Operating System (32bit or 64bit) and simple run the installer.

*Update the system PATH:*

`Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables`

In the System variables list, click Path, click Edit and then New.
Add `C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin` value.

To check if it's working, go to cmd, navigate to your project folder and type

`"manage makemessages -l de".`

You may have to configure the path to store translations. Create a dir named "locale" in your project dir and point to it at settings.py

Also make sure to set the local path in settings.py file:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    BASE_DIR + 'locale/', )
```

Comment: does not work for me python 3, django 1.11.7. I use the NBajanca that works for me

Comment: this worked for me, but had to restart windows after env variable addition

Answer (score 24):

Django removed this explanation from the recent docs and it took me some time to found it so i pasted it here before this old documentation goes offline:

Source: [Django Docs 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows)

Download the following zip files from the [GNOME servers](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/)

- gettext-runtime-X.zip
- gettext-tools-X.zip

> X is the version number (It needs to be 0.15 or higher)

Extract the contents of the `bin\` directories in both files to the same folder on your system (i.e. `C:\Program Files\gettext-utils`)

**Update the system PATH:**

`Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables`

In the System variables list, click Path, click Edit and then New.
Add `C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin` value.

> You may also use gettext binaries you have obtained elsewhere, so long as the xgettext --version command works properly. Do not attempt to use Django translation utilities with a gettext package if the command xgettext --version entered at a Windows command prompt causes a popup window saying “xgettext.exe has generated errors and will be closed by Windows”.

After doing this I tested and `./manage.py makemessages -l pt` works

Comment: For my setup the **libstdc++-6.dll** was additionally required beside the /bin from  _gettext-tools-dev_xxxx_win32.zip_ and _gettext-runtime_xxxx_win32.zip_

Comment: Please provide a link to download the ``.dll`` and I will add a note in my answer

Comment: As far as I remember it's bundled with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017 and/or with the Rust Compiler https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/i686-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe

Comment: I'm not adding this info as it doesn't seem to be necessarily related and when I search for `libstdc++-6.dll`, there are multiple complaints related to different software.

Comment: worked with python 3.7.4 and django 2.0 thank you, one small thing i want to add i was trying with pycharm terminal that's not working then i tried with cmd then worked

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. After that I downloaded and installed this and everything worked.https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Let me save you many hours that I had to spend in order to solve this.

One of the possibilities is that after you have successfully done all the above and done

```
pip install python-gettext
```

you may have improperly configured your IDE or venv. In order to bypass this, go to the command prompt, navigate to your root folder and run `py manage.py makemessages` from there. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the relevant files and adding their location to the path, I still had the same problem. But then I ran the django-admin makemessages -l sr-Latn command in the command prompt instead of powershell and it worked. More preciselly,  I first got notification that libstdc++-6.dll is missing, and after installing it in the relevant directory as explained here https://www.dll-files.com/support/#200924305 , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, for sharing your experience.
The best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574890/3786145.
Just after many efforts, it is good to mention that:
if you want to use this tool in Pycharm IDE such that works in a different environment(wich python path and path variable are changed (eg: OSGeo)), it is necessary to make a batch file and add these two directories to the changed path:

```
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin
path %path%;C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\lib\gettext
SET PYCHARM="D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"
start "PyCharm aware of get text" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

After running Pycharm using this batch file, go to tools/Run manage.py Task. In the appeared window write your command like this:
makemessages -l 'fa_IR'
for more information refer to:
[1] https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-message-files.html
[2] https://silverspringenergy.com/using-pycharm-as-an-ide-for-qgis-3-plugin-development-2/